# Why nullable fields is not working in this WSO2 DSS INSERT query?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wso2, integration, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am working on **WSO2 EI** version **6.1.1** and I am finding a big problem trying to implement a simple **DSS** INSERT query that have to insert a new record into a table allowing that some fields are **null**.

This is my **DSS** code related to this spwcific query definition and the related operation:

```
<query id="insert_user" returnGeneratedKeys="true" useConfig="user_db">
    <sql>
        insert into User(
            application_UID,
            country_id,
            localization_id,
            local_user_id,
            isActive,
            isFullProfile,
            birth_date,
            gender,
            prefix
            )
        values(
            :application_UID,
            :country_id,
            :localization_id,
            :local_user_id,
            :is_active,
            :is_full_profile,
            :birth_date,
            :gender,
            :prefix
        )
    </sql>
    <result element="GeneratedKeys" rowName="Entry" useColumnNumbers="true">
        <element column="1" name="ID" xsdType="integer"/>
    </result>
    <param name="application_UID" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="country_id" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
    <param name="localization_id" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
    <param name="local_user_id" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
    <param name="is_active" sqlType="BIT"/>
    <param name="is_full_profile" sqlType="BIT"/>
    <param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="birth_date" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="gender" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="prefix" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>

<operation name="AddUser">
    <call-query href="insert_user">
        <with-param name="application_UID" query-param="application_UID"/>
        <with-param name="country_id" query-param="country_id"/>
        <with-param name="localization_id" query-param="localization_id"/>
        <with-param name="local_user_id" query-param="local_user_id"/>
        <with-param name="is_active" query-param="is_active"/>
        <with-param name="is_full_profile" query-param="is_full_profile"/>
        <with-param name="birth_date" query-param="birth_date"/>
        <with-param name="gender" query-param="gender"/>
        <with-param name="prefix" query-param="prefix"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
```

The last 3 fiedls are **nullable** on my DB and as you can see I defined these fields in this way (I used the **defaultValue="#{NULL}"** to make these fields nullable):

```
<param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="birth_date" sqlType="STRING"/>
<param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="gender" sqlType="STRING"/>
<param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="prefix" sqlType="STRING"/>
```

The problem is that if I go into the try it tool and I perform this query:

```
<body>
   <p:AddUser xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:application_UID>xxx</p:application_UID>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:country_id>1</p:country_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:localization_id>1</p:localization_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:local_user_id>1</p:local_user_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_active>true</p:is_active>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_full_profile>true</p:is_full_profile>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:birth_date>?</p:birth_date>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:gender>?</p:gender>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:prefix>?</p:prefix>
   </p:AddUser>
</body>
```

(as you can see I am not setting the values of the last 3 nullable fields) I am obtaining this error message in the output ot the Try It tool:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Value>axis2ns393:DATABASE_ERROR</soapenv:Value>
   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Nested Exception:- javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1 DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: user-dss Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1524668046564userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Current Request Name: AddUser Current Params: {local_user_id=1, is_active=true, gender=?, prefix=?, birth_date=?, is_full_profile=true, application_UID=xxx, country_id=1, localization_id=1} Nested Exception:- com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1  </soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail>
      <axis2ns392:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns392="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <axis2ns392:current_params>{local_user_id=1, is_active=true, gender=?, prefix=?, birth_date=?, is_full_profile=true, application_UID=xxx, country_id=1, localization_id=1}</axis2ns392:current_params>
         <axis2ns392:source_data_service>
            <axis2ns392:data_service_name>user-dss</axis2ns392:data_service_name>
            <axis2ns392:description>N/A</axis2ns392:description>
            <axis2ns392:location>/opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1524668046564userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs</axis2ns392:location>
            <axis2ns392:default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice</axis2ns392:default_namespace>
         </axis2ns392:source_data_service>
         <axis2ns392:ds_code>DATABASE_ERROR</axis2ns392:ds_code>
         <axis2ns392:nested_exception>com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1</axis2ns392:nested_exception>
         <axis2ns392:current_request_name>AddUser</axis2ns392:current_request_name>
      </axis2ns392:DataServiceFault>
   </soapenv:Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

and into my Carbon log I have something like this:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-25 16:57:13,853] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver}
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1524668046564userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=1, is_active=true, gender=?, prefix=?, birth_date=?, is_full_profile=true, application_UID=xxx, country_id=1, localization_id=1}
Nested Exception:-
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1


        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:357)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1524668046564userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=1, is_active=true, gender=?, prefix=?, birth_date=?, is_full_profile=true, application_UID=xxx, country_id=1, localization_id=1}
Nested Exception:-
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1

        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
        ... 12 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-25 16:57:13,855] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request for : /services/user-dss.SOAP12Endpoint/AddUser {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1524668046564userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=1, is_active=true, gender=?, prefix=?, birth_date=?, is_full_profile=true, application_UID=xxx, country_id=1, localization_id=1}
Nested Exception:-
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1


        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBUtils.createAxisFault(DBUtils.java:740)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1524668046564userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=1, is_active=true, gender=?, prefix=?, birth_date=?, is_full_profile=true, application_UID=xxx, country_id=1, localization_id=1}
Nested Exception:-
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '?' for column 'birth_date' at row 1

        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:357)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
        ... 9 more
```

It happens similar error if I use a query like this:

```
<body>
   <p:AddUser xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:application_UID>xxx</p:application_UID>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:country_id>1</p:country_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:localization_id>1</p:localization_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:local_user_id>1</p:local_user_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_active>true</p:is_active>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_full_profile>true</p:is_full_profile>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:birth_date></p:birth_date>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:gender></p:gender>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:prefix></p:prefix>
   </p:AddUser>
</body>
```

Also tried in this way obtaining the same problem:

```
<body>
   <p:AddUser xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:application_UID>xxx</p:application_UID>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:country_id>1</p:country_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:localization_id>1</p:localization_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:local_user_id>1</p:local_user_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_active>true</p:is_active>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_full_profile>true</p:is_full_profile>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:birth_date>null</p:birth_date>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:gender>null</p:gender>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:prefix>null</p:prefix>
   </p:AddUser>
</body>
```

The only way that I found woks is to perform a query that exclude these parameters, using this query it works fine:

```
<body>
   <p:AddUser xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:application_UID>xxx</p:application_UID>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:country_id>1</p:country_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:localization_id>1</p:localization_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:local_user_id>1</p:local_user_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_active>true</p:is_active>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_full_profile>true</p:is_full_profile>
   </p:AddUser>
</body>
```

In this case works and the record is correctly insert in my DB table, but I can't use this because I have to call this DSS service from an ESB flow and have to work using all the parameters (if a parameter is not setted or null) it have to insert null.

Why? How can I fix this query and calling it with **NULL** values saving NULL as value of my nullable field?

Comment: Hi @AndreaNobili
May be this below link will help.

https://medium.com/@lashan/inserting-null-to-a-database-through-wso2-dss-e1ab35eee386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

IMHO it is expected behavior

```
  <p:birth_date>?</p:birth_date>
  <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
  <p:gender>?</p:gender>
  <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
  <p:prefix>?</p:prefix>
```

here you are sending text  `?` as date, so mysql correctly throws an expression

in case  of  `<p:birth_date></p:birth_date>`  the value is an empty string and having string `null` won't help either.

> How can I fix this query

I don't work with mysql much, I'd suggest using str_to_date function which should represent null or empty string as null value